# How to set activeColor to SwitchThemeData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-switch, buttoncolor

`activeColor` property is available inside `Switch` but not available in `SwitchThemeData`. How can we get the same effect as `activeColor` in `SwitchThemeData` as a global property for `Switch`

Comment: tried `SwitchThemeData.thumbColor`?

Comment: Yeah, `activeColor` handles both `thumbColor` and `trackColor`

Answer (score 0):

the property `toggleableActiveColor` have been deprecated (according to flutter [website](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/toggleable-active-color))
 you have to use `ColorScheme.secondary.` to change it's active color